# VMware Linux Crashed, Cannot Boot

Tags: linux, rhel, vmware, vmware-workstation

I accidentally plugged out the external HDD while the virtual machine is still running, when I plugged it in again the system show message as follow:

```
Generating "run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view to view system logs.
You might want to save "run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot 
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.

:/#
```

I installed Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 64-bit on VMware Workstation 15 on an external hard disk(because there is not enough disk space on the local hard disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution

just run this command

```
:/# xfs_repair -v -L /dev/dm-0
```

Thank you JH from
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364041/381573